# How do I use SystemJS Builder buildStatic?

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm

I am trying to do a simple example using SystemJS Builder by building a SFX bundle, but I cannot get it to work. I cannot figure out how to call exported functions that were in the bundle. Am I missing something obvious?

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="app.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        all();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

gulpfile.js

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var Builder = require('systemjs-builder');

gulp.task('default', function(cb) {
    var builder = new Builder('.', './jspm.config.js');
    builder.buildStatic('src/app.js', 'dist/app.bundle.js').then(cb());
});
```

app.js

```
import { hello } from 'src/app/hello';

export function all() {
    hello();
}
```

hello.js

```
export function hello() {
    console.log("hello");
};
```

When I try to load index.html, it loads the app.bundle.js file correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to call all() and I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: all is not defined` in Chrome.

The bundle file looks reasonable, I think:

```
// ... Some minified SystemJS content...

(["1"], [], function($__System) {

$__System.register("2", [], function (_export) {
    "use strict";

    _export("hello", hello);

    function hello() {
        console.log("hello");
    }

    return {
        setters: [],
        execute: function () {
            ;
        }
    };
});

$__System.register('1', ['2'], function (_export) {
    'use strict';

    var hello;

    _export('all', all);

    function all() {
        hello();
    }

    return {
        setters: [function (_) {
            hello = _.hello;
        }],
        execute: function () {}
    };
});

})
(function(factory) {

  if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd)
    define([], factory);
  else if (typeof module == 'object' && module.exports && typeof require == 'function')
    module.exports = factory();
  else
    factory();
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's related to your problem, but I think you want `.then(cb)` instead of `.then(cb())`.  The latter executes the callback as soon as `.then` is executed.  The former passes the callback to `.then`, and will be called once `buildStatic` resolves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting the `all` function does not mean it's accessible by the global object (`window` in the browser).
It just means that it can be imported using a module loaded (e.g. systemjs).
When creating a self-executing bundle you should just load the bundle file in the browser (as you already do) and do all bootstrapping also in the js files that are going to be in the bundle.

If you really need to access the all function in that script tag you must add the function to the global object.
in your app.js

```
window.all = all;
```

But i don't think this is the way its intended to be used.